# How can always ignore a file while merge

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, ignore

I have a configuration file that is different in two branches.
I want that this config file is tracked inside each branch but always ignored when merging branches.

So, after i merge the two branches, the file remains in each branch the same as it was before merging.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to create the `ours` merge driver unless you already have one. To do this, run this command:

```
 git config merge.ours.driver true
```

This driver will allow you to prefer destination branch's version of a file during a merge session.

Secondly, let's call your branches `A` and `B`.

On branch `A`, in the directory of the file, create a file called `.gitattributes` with this line in it:

```
myconfig.conf merge=ours
```

Then add and commit the `.gitattributes` file.

It'll make git always keep `A`'s version of `myconfig.conf` when merging **`B` to `A`**. If you also need to merge **`A` to `B`**, repeat the same steps for the `B` branch.

Comment: did you mean `git config --global merge.ours.driver true` ?

Comment: Are you sure you're doing a clean merge? Try discarding all changes by `git checkout -f HEAD` and then redoing the merge.

Comment: @CPJ Do you have a fast forward merge?  Be sure to use `--no-ff`

Comment: @EdwardThomson Yes, I have fast forward merge. But I just want that file to be ignored whatever way i do the merge.

Comment: @CPJ you *must* use `--no-ff` in this case.  A fast forward merge does not perform a merge; it detects that a merge need not occur and sets the branch to point to the other commit.  There is no opportunity for ignoring anything.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Well, actually there is an opportunity for ignoring. Let's say I have a main branch that I keep ready for production, meaning that I have a settings file set for compiling other files in production mode. Than I have a bunch of branches where I set the same config file for development. When I merge one development branch into the master, I would like it to ignore that config file. That way I don't always have to continuously manually config that file for production, or revert it to the last master branch version.

Comment: @CPJ right.  If you want that you *must* use `--no-ff`.  Otherwise a fast forward can occur which means the commit trom the other branch will simply become the new branch.  The exact literal commit.  With no ignore processing.

Answer (score 1):

To use the hook below, do e.g.

```
echo path/to/protected/file config >> .git/info/attributes
git config --add branch.server1.protect-attr config
```

The attribute `config` and the `protect-attr` branch item are inventions just for this.

- `.git/hooks/post-merge`:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  protect="$(git config --get-all branch."$(git branch|sed -n 's/^\*.//p')".protect-attr)"
  if test ! -z "$protect"; then
      git diff --name-only HEAD@{1} HEAD \
      | git check-attr --stdin $protect \
      | sed -n '/: unspecified$/!s,:.*,,p' \
      | sort -u \
      | sed -e 's,^,git checkout HEAD@{1} -- ",' -e 's,$," # protected file changed by merge,'
  fi
  ```

and merges into branch config will pop reversion commands when changes to `foo` or any other file you've tagged as a config get merged into a branch that's marked to protect them..

```
$ git merge wip
Updating 9906beb..888556e
Fast-forward
 foo | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
git checkout HEAD@{1} -- "foo" # protected file changed by merge
```

You could also add a `|sh -x` pipe stage to just do the reversion -- and even do a `git commit --amend --no-edit` to go full-auto.  This is pretty much a starter kit, see the [githooks](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html), [gitattributes](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) and [git config](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) manpages for more.

There's a [`libgit2`](http://libgit2.github.com) project that's working on reimplementing git in a more embedding-friendly way, it isn't git but has its advantages if you don't need all of git.  Unfortunately it's not complete enough yet to handle this, so be sure you're using [the full git thing](http://git-scm.com/downloads) and not one of the limited clients.